# Jquery hasClass show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am about to make a menu in drupal with jquery, I need the link to when it has class active it need to be shown.

```
(function ($) {
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.region-sidebar-first .block-menu ul.menu').children('li').children('a').hasClass('active').hide();
  $('.region-sidebar-first .block-menu h2').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().children().slideUp(400);           
   $(this).next('.content').children('.menu').slideDown(400);
  });
 });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use jquery hasClass()

Full information here : http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

```
if ($('#item1').hasClass("active")) {
 DoSomething()
} else { 
 DoSomethingElse()
}
```

You can also use `:visible`

```
if ($('#item1:visible')) {
     DoSomething()
    } else { 
     DoSomethingElse()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this

```
var myDiv = $('.region-sidebar-first .block-menu ul.menu').children('li').children('a');

if(myDiv.hasClass('active')){
   myDiv.hide();
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but it hides all a it only need to hide the one with the class active